# jQuery FlipCounter count each digit

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using [FlipCounter](https://github.com/waldobronchart/FlipCounter) to count up from 0 to 3,000 but, instead of counting each digit ([like the example](https://cdn.rawgit.com/waldobronchart/FlipCounter/master/examples/quickupdate/index.htm)) it's jumping 1,000 at a time.

Any advice/help would be much appreciated!

**JS**

```
  function total(){
    var length = defaultArray.length+'000';
    $("#flipcounter").flipCounterInit();
    function updateLoop(){
      $("#flipcounter").flipCounterUpdate(length);
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        updateLoop();
      }, 5000);
    }
    updateLoop();
  }
  total();
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="totalsubmissions">
  <div class="inner">
    <div id="flipcounter" style="text-align: center;"></div>
    <p>Total word submissions</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Project URL: https://cdn.rawgit.com/adamkwadsworth/oup-interactive-content/master/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to do something like this. Then when the number gets to 3000, don't do setTimeout

```
$("#flipcounter").flipCounterInit();

var number = 0;
function updateLoop() {
    number++;
    $("#flipcounter").flipCounterUpdate(number);
    if (number <= 3000) {
        window.setTimeout(updateLoop, 5000);
    }
}
updateLoop();
```

Comment: Thank you Waldo, I really appreciate your help!